# MySQL error: Duplicate entry 'email@domain.com ' for key 3

Tags: mysql, duplicate-data

This is my table

[image]

And this is my php query code

```
// Check for unique username
    $quser = "SELECT user_id FROM users
        WHERE (username = '$u' AND email = 'e')
            ";

    $ruser = mysqli_query($dbc, $quser) or die("MySQL error: " .   mysqli_error($dbc) . "<hr>\nQuery: $quser");

if(mysqli_num_rows($ruser) == 0 ){

//do the INSERT INTO query
$q = " INSERT INTO users (lang_id, username, pass, email, active, registration_date)
               VALUES ( '$l','$u', SHA1('$p'), '$e', '$a', NOW() )
             ";

}else{

echo 'That email address has already been registered.';
}
```

When I test it by entering the duplicate email address into the HTML form (assumed that the form validation is good), it returns error as shown below:

```
MySQL error: Duplicate entry 'email@domain.com ' for key 3
---------------------------------------------------------
Query: SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE (username = 'dsfdsf' AND email = 'e')
```

And of course, the value is NOT entered into the table yet.

These are the solutions I have been trying:

1/ I removed the unique indexes for username and email, data gets inserted, but still duplicated, which i NEVER expect.

2/ I tried duplicate username, but not email, the same error returns.

The question in my head now is why does it NOT returns my customized error message as in }else{ part, but the one generated by server or so?

Can you help? Thanks

Comment: Did you notice `or die("MySQL error: " ` part in your code by chance?

Comment: Yes, I did. I commented it out. but no success either

Answer (score 1):

Chaging your request to

```
$quser = "SELECT user_id FROM users
        WHERE username = '$u' 
           or email = '$e'
            ";
```

should do the trick. 
You missed a `$` at email as well as this query only returned values if both are set... so only duplicate email or duplicate username wouldn't be catched.

Maybe you can catch these kind of errors with some exception handling to avoid bad luck on timing (2 processes are inserting data at the same time).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ruser = mysqli_query($dbc, " SELECT * user_id FROM users 
WHERE username like '$u' or  email like '$e' ");
```

in the select Query Email should be $e and not just e

try

```
$res=mysql_query("select * from users 
where username like '$u' or email like '$e' ");

if(mysql_num_rows($res)==0)
mysql_query(" insert into users
(lang_id, username, pass, email, active,registration_date) values
('$l','$u','$p','$e','$a',NOW()) ");

else
echo "Duplicate entry";
```

**This may be the Error**
Oh the problem is that you have user_id in your table as primary and it should be not be null , even user_level cannot be NULL, hence everytime you insert a new row you should insert a value for user_id and user_level

```
mysql_query(" insert into users
(lang_id, username, pass, email, active,registration_date,user_id,user_level) 
values('$l','$u','$p','$e','$a',NOW(),$userid,'$user_level') ");
```

hope this solves your problem

Comment: This will also not catch cases where only username or email is a duplicate

Comment: Oh i didnt change query that much, just saw the error and posted, thanks for the comment!

Comment: I corrected e to $e, but no suceed; and change NAD to OR. Same error still occurs.

Comment: sorry Aamir. I just tested your edited code with no success. I then switched OR to AND, it returned the same original error in my question. If i keep the OR as per your code, it does not return any 'congratulation message', and the data does not get inserted. I am not sure if something is wrong with my table structure or not?

Comment: I read somewhere on the internet that it is said that WHERE only works with single record for checking duplicated record. So I doubt that WHERE function may cause the problem?

Comment: your are not inserting values for user_id and user_level.. read my edited answer above

Comment: @Aamir: You know what?  the user_level column has a default value of 0, and the user_id applies the auto_increment, which tells MySQL to use the next-highest number as the user_id value for each added record. So, i think we do not have to provide their values in this query. Do you think so?